# Docker compose Connection refused by container

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a wordpress site that we do local work on through a docker container. It was working fine, then all of a sudden stopped. I can connect to the database via MySQL workbench, I can ssh into the docker container, I can even ping the container's IP and it's fine.

Here is my docker-compose file, any and all insight is appreciated.

```
version: '2'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
     volumes:
       - ./html:/var/www/html
volumes:
    db_data:
```